# Applying Daemon to Web App

Tags: python, daemon

If I've got a python web app that needs to load a few heavy modules into memory I seem to run into an issue of the time it takes to load. Once loaded the functions I run take just a few milliseconds, however the time to load the script itself could take up to half a second which just isn't acceptable.

So, (forgive me for the over simplification, I am new to python), I am figuring I need to "daemonize" my script so that I only load it once and when I need to run a function am calling an already running and loaded script.

I found a good daemon example implementation [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

My question is, how do I apply this to MY script?  Do I simply start the daemon and because it is continually running whatever other scripts that are called will also stay in memory?  Or do I have to implement it into my program?

For simplicities sake lets say this is my program:

```
import sys
import reallyBigModule

print(sys.argv[1:])
```

$ python helloWorld.py "hello world"

Comment: What kind of webapp is this? Are you using some WSGI framework? If so, which one?

Comment: @Wooble no framework.  It is going to be a REST app.

Comment: So how are you running it? Plain CGI? One of the many, many reasons not to do that is the slowness involved in starting a new interpreter for each request. Consider using something like Flask.